# How to cast {PropertyName} fromFluentValidation to specific Controls in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, fluentvalidation

I'm using `FluentValidation` in my Windows Form App to validate what the user inputed from
my controllers `TextBoxName`, `TextBoxAddress`, `TextBoxContactInfo` and `ComboboxGender`.

On my Validator, I have set up a `RuleFor(user => user.DomainModel...)`that will prompt an error if the user puts empty or invalid characters then it will prohibit the program from saving the data into the database.

```
    RuleFor(user => user.Name)
        .Cascade(CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure)
        .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Provide {PropertyName}")
        .Must(BeAValidName).WithMessage("{PropertyName} contains invalid characters")
        .Length(2, 50).WithMessage("Length ({TotalLength}) of {PropertyName} is between 2-50 
        characters");
```

On my Form, I have tried exposing the value of `{PropertyName}` when errors occurred but it only returned the generic value `{System.Windows.Forms.Textbox}` thereby can't be assigned back into its specific Textbox or Combobox control name(i.e. TextBoxName.Name).

```
        if(validationResult.IsValid == false)
        {
            MetroTextBox mtxtb = new MetroTextBox();
            List<string> errorList = new List<string>();

            foreach (ValidationFailure failure in validationResult.Errors)
            {
                //my attempt to assign the {PropertyName} from FluentValidation to workable Control, but this does not work
                mtxtb.Name = failure.PropertyName;
                Control[] ctrl = gboxUser.Controls.Find(mtxtb.Name.Replace(" ", ""), true);
                if (ctrl.Length != 0)
                {
                    Control found = ctrl[0];

                    //To print the exposed Controls value and to see that the code works
                    Console.WriteLine(found.ToString());
                }
                //To add the error/s in errorList
                errorList.Add(failure.ErrorMessage);

                //To select the Controls and modify color properties
                mtxtb.SelectAll();
                mtxtb.BackColor = Color.MistyRose;


            }
            //To prompt an error of empty and invalid data  
            if(errorList.Count>0)
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.AppendLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, errorList));
                MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString() + Environment.NewLine, "Error", 
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
```

How can I do this? and where do I write the code for this?

What I'm trying to accomplish is:
If `TextBox/Combobox` can't be validated, it will prompt an error and the program will `SetFocus` or change the `BackColor` to the specific `TextBoxName/ComboBoxName Control` where the error occurred.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little cumbersome, but it keeps the validation rules separate from the UI.

- For each input control requiring validation, create the associated "Validating" event.
- Grab the object from the datasource for the current record and stage in a "preview" object.
- Set the attribute in the preview object to the value sent by the sender.
- Pass that object into the validator.
- Use the validation results to populate the ErrorProvider.

This option still requires mapping the UI to the corresponding attribute, but doesn't bury the rules in the UI.

```
private void mtxtb_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    string error = null;
    if (myDataSource.Count > 0)
    {
        User preview = (User)myDataSource.CurrencyManager.Current;
        preview.Name= ((TextBox)sender).Text;
        UserValidator validator = new UserValidator();
        ValidationResult _validationResults = validator.Validate(preview);
        ValidationFailure failure = _validationResults.Errors.Find(x => x.PropertyName == "Name");
        if (failure != null)
        {
            error = failure.ErrorMessage;
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
    errorProvider1.SetError((Control)sender, error);
}
```